# Optimal VCV matrix solution of multivariate loglikelhood

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

I asked a related question  yesterday and got a brilliant answer from Ross B. However I still have difficulties. I have the following analog of multivariate loglikehood function (minus 2*log-likehood to be precise)
$$
L(C)=Tr(XX^TC + \log(C))~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$

This is the fully matrix representation of multivariate log-likelihood. My goal is to minimize it with respect to $C$. Now $C$ is inverse of covariance matrix I am looking for and it is parametrized as follows:
$$
C=(D + UFU^T)^{-1}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~              (2)
$$
Here $C$ is symmetric nxn matrix. $D$ is a strictly positive diagonal, $U$ is $nxp$ mattrix , $p<n$ and $F$ is $pxp$ symmetric positive definite matrix.
 $D$ and $F$ are parameters. It is easy to see that in global minimzation over $C$ without parametrization we have
$$
L^\prime_c(C)=XX^T-C^{-1}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(3)
$$
So the optimal covariance achieving the derivative $L^\prime=0$ is $\Sigma = C^{-1} =XX^T$ 
But within (2) the problem is more difficult. 
Ross.B helped to get derivative of $L(C(D,F)^\prime_F$ and I calculated myself the derivative of $L(C(D,F)^\prime_D$:
$$
L(C(D,F))^\prime_F=-U^TC(XX^T-C^{-1})CU \\
L(C(D,F))^\prime_D=-diag(C(XX^T-C^{-1})C) \\~~~~~~~~~(4)
$$
Everything seems pretty much nice and symmetric (I hope they are correct), but I cannot solve the system 
$$
L(C(D,F))^\prime_F=0\\
L(C(D,F))^\prime_D=0
$$

From other considerations I suspect that the optimal solution $D^*$ and $F^*$ is  defined as follows:
$$
F^*=U^{+} XX^T U^{+T}
$$
CORRECTION:
$$
D^*=diag((I-UU^+)XX^T(I-UU^+))
$$
or may be 
$$
D^*=diag((XX^T-UFU^T)=diag(XX^T-UU^+XX^TU^{+T}U^T)
$$
But I cannot prove or disprove it. Any help would be very appreciated.